# What's the forward and reverse zooming?

Tags: zoom

Is there a tradition that enjoins what direction of mouse scrolling zooms in/out? (In other words, what considered forward/reverse zooming?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling the surface of the mousewheel away from you - traditional upscroll [as opposed to 'natural'] is used as zoom in for all apps I've ever used that have that capability.

Presumably [though I never use it] if a user has natural scroll enabled, they will expect [& get] the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia
[Scroll wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel):

> Most often, rolling the upper side of the wheel away from your body is
> to scroll "upward" or "forward", and the reverse direction is to
> scroll "downward" or "backward".
>
> In a graphical user interface, the "upward" motion moves contents of
> the window downward (and the scrollbar thumb, if present, upward), and
> vice versa. In other configurations (sometimes called "natural
> scrolling") the effect is inverted.
> [...]
> The scroll wheel was popularized by the Microsoft IntelliMouse in 1996 along with support for the mouse wheel in Microsoft Office 97.

The zoom in/out operation by the scroll wheel of Microsoft Windows was
copied by all other computer manufacturers and so became the de facto standard.

Nevertheless, sometimes (rarely) I come across a program where the action of the
scroll wheel is the opposite of what I'm used too, and that is really annoying.